# JavaScript Generators flow understanding

Tags: javascript, generator

I tried small piece of code for generators

```js
function* listener() {
  console.log('listening');
  while (true) {
    console.log('before yield'); /** Why this is getting print in end again**/
    let msg = yield;
    console.log('after yield', msg);
  }
}

let l = listener();
l.next('are you there?');
console.log('-----');
l.next('how are you?');
```

**Output:**

```
listening
before yield
-----
after yield how are you?
before yield
```

Everything looks ok but the only thing which I am not sure about how come control going back to print 'before yield' in the end again.

Could someone help me out here to understand the concept.

Thanks

Comment: You have an infinite loop (`while (true)`), you will always loop back to "before yield", what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: From my understanding, [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) pauses the function right after `console.log('before yield');`

When you call .next() the function resumes and pauses at the line where you "yielded".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that passing an argument to the first call of `next` has no use: this value is only relevant when the generator function has encountered a `yield` expression. Be aware that the generator function executes **nothing** until the first `next` call is made.

When you call `next` the first time, the generator function starts executing from the top until it encounters `yield`. There its execution is suspended.

When you make the second `next` call, the argument you passed determines the value of the yield expression. The generator function resumes execution and assigns that value to `msg` and then continues up until the next `yield`. This is where the output is made where you wonder about.

Here's a visualisation:

| main | listener |
| --- | --- |
| `let l = listener();` |  |
| `l.next('are you there?');` |  |
|  | `console.log('listening');` |
|  | `while (true) {` |
|  | `console.log('before yield');` |
|  | `yield` |
|  | (suspend) |
| `console.log('-----');` |  |
| `l.next('how are you?');` |  |
|  | (resume) |
|  | `msg = 'how are you?';` |
|  | `console.log('after yield', msg);` |
|  | `while (true) {` |
|  | `console.log('before yield');` |
|  | `yield` |
|  | (suspend) |